mdframe-boxes within boxes won't break properly
I'm currently working on a project for which I would like to use the mdframed-package for some structuring.
Doing this I would like to create boxes within boxes, but when I do so and the inside boxes get really large, they won't break with the end of the page. Is there any way to fix this? I have looked it up and there is a similar problem for the tcolorbox package, for which there apparently is no fix...
The command I am using looks something like this:
\newcommand{\graybox}[1]{\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=lightgray!20!white, topline=false, bottomline=false, rightline=false, linewidth=4pt] #1 \end{mdframed}}

Thanks to everyone in advance!

no. Inside boxes can't break, beside this: tcolorbox has much more features, there is nothing that you can do with mdframed that it can't do too.
